# Reading Firebase database in two chunks Flutter

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am creating a Flutter app that loads a large amount of data from a Firebase database.  The idea I had is to load the first 20 or so observations from the database when the app is initially loading, and then continue to load the remaining data as the app continues.

Essentially, I want to load the first 20 observations asynchronously and return them.  These could then be used in case the user requires data before all the data finishes loading.  As the app continues, I want the rest of the data to be loaded asynchronously and collected into a list.

So far, this is the solution I have come up with:

```
Stream<List<Event>> chunkLoad(int firstChunk, String location) {
  StreamController<List<Event>> controller = new StreamController<List<Event>>();

  StreamSubscription<Event> subscription;
  List<Event> chunkedOutput = [];
  DatabaseReference ref = database.reference().child(location);

  void startSubscription(){
    subscription = ref.onValue.listen((Event event){
      chunkedOutput.add(event);
      if (chunkedOutput.length == firstChunk)
        controller.add(chunkedOutput);
    });
    subscription.onDone((){
      controller.add(chunkedOutput);
      controller.close();
    });
  }

  void endSubscription(){
    subscription.cancel();
    subscription = null;
  }

  void pauseSubscription(){subscription.pause();}
  void resumeSubscription(){subscription.resume();}

  controller = new StreamController<List<String>>(
    onListen: startSubscription,
    onCancel: endSubscription,
    onPause: pauseSubscription,
    onResume: resumeSubscription,
  );
  return controller.stream;
}
```

This method is intended to subscribe to `onValue` events and return the first `firstChunk` of them as the first value from the stream, and then return all of the received events as the second and final value from the stream.  However, I'm not sure how I can use this method to accomplish what I'm looking to do.

Again, I'd like to listen to the first event from this stream and handle it normally, while also listening for the last event from this stream and putting the result into a static list.  Is this possible?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have found the solution please share it. I need the exact same thing for me. Thank You